# Linux redirection help needed

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a script that when run, will access the /var/log/secure file and report how many failed attempts occurred that day, append the output to a file called failed in this type of format:

Date: 02/15/14  Time: 10:30  Number of failed attempts: 8

and output should be done inside the script using file redirection so the standard output goes into failed.log and standard error go into error.log file.

My code (test.sh) is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
 for i in $(date)

 do
 mdy=$($i "+%m/%d/%Y)
 md=$($i "+%m %d")
 tme=$($i "+ H:%M)
 fail=$(grep Failed /var/log/secure | grep $md | wc -l

 echo "Date: $mdy Time: $tme Number of failed attempts: $fail"

 done
```

What am I doing wrong?

I did the for loop thinking the i would be the date command and the mdy will show mm/dd/yy, tme will be HH:MM and md would be use to grep the var/log/secure for the failed logins.

Once I get the output I want, I will be able to do the redirects via 
sh test.sh > failed.log 2> error.log

Comment: By the way, `grep -c` is equivalent to `grep | wc -l`.

Comment: What is that `$($i "+%m/%d/%Y")` supposed to do?

Comment: For that matter, what's the `for` loop even doing? You loop over the components of the current `date` output...?

Comment: nneonneo - it is what I thought I am supposed to do to get the info - taking all the information from the date command.  I am going to put it into an error.log file so I can parse that file to see how many failed logins there have been.

Comment: Please tell me exactly what you want your date parsing to look like.  I deleted my previous comment after I realized I wasn't understanding what you were looking for.

Comment: Date: 02/15/14 Time: 10:30 Number of failed attempts: 8

Comment: I am trying to create a script that when run, will access the /var/log/secure file and report how many failed attempts occurred that day, append the output to a file called failed with the above format and output should be done inside the script using file redirection so the standard output goes into failed.log and standard error go into error.log file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this?  I really don't know how you want it to look parsed but using these variables you can do it as you will.  However, your for loop is not doing what you want it to, I believe.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -- $(date)
DAYNAME=$1; MONTH=$2; DAY=$3; TIME=$4; YEAR=$6
ATTEMPTS=$(grep -iw 'Failed\|$2\|$3' /var/log/secure | wc -l)
echo "Date: $MONTH $DAY $YEAR Time: $TIME Number of failed attempts: $ATTEMPTS"
```

Comment: Simpler to do `set -- $(date)` and then `DAYNAME=$1; MONTH=$2; DAY=$3; TIME=$4; YEAR=$6`

Comment: Thanks tripleee.  
OP, please try changes.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about redirection, I am doing it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

THIS_SCRIPT_NAME=$( basename $0 )
LOG_DIR='/var/log'
DATE_POSTFIX=$( date '+_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S' )
LOG_FILE="${LOG_DIR}/${THIS_SCRIPT_NAME}${DATE_POSTFIX}.log"

if [ ! -d "$LOG_DIR" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$LOG_DIR"
fi

exec 1>>"$LOG_FILE" 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the unnecessary parts and fixing what's left, your script could look like this.  There is no need for a `for` loop if you just want to process a single date.

```
#!/bin/bash
mdy=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y")
md=$(date "+%m %d")
tme=$(date "+%H:%M")
# Assuming the date stamp always precedes the message
fail=$(grep -c "$md.*Failed" /var/log/secure)
echo "Date: $mdy Time: $tme Number of failed attempts: $fail"
```

There isn't really much that could go wrong; mainly, standard error would contain a message if you did not have read access to `/var/log/secure` or it did not exist.

There are ways to avoid calling `date` more than once but that is hardly going to be the performance bottleneck here.